# MySQL source command Failed to open file 'C:\Users\lestr\OneDrive\Desktop\test_db_master\employees.sql', error: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql

I ran the script in mysqlsh using the "\source" command, got the error:
"Failed to open file 'show_elapsed.sql', error: No such file or directory"

Comment: check the directory where the employees.sql is

Comment: i change directory,but dump Failed to open file 'load_salaries1.dump', error: No such file or directory
Failed to open file 'load_salaries2.dump', error: No such file or directory
Failed to open file 'load_salaries3.dump', error: No such file or directory
Failed to open file 'show_elapsed.sql', error: No such file or directory

Comment: please, try edit your question and makes it clear

Comment: Are you trying to source `employees.sql`, `show_elapsed.sql`, `load_salaries2.dump`, `load_salaries3.dump`, all of them or none of them?

Comment: That's it, I fixed it, I didn't specify the path to the file in the script